# Varargs macro to either execute a function call or convert it to a string

Tags: c++

I'd like to optionally call a function or convert it to a string (print it out). The following doesn't work:

```
#if !defined(ENABLE_FUNCS)
#define APPLY(func, ...) do { (func(__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
#else
#define APPLY(func, ...) \
  do {std::clog << #func << #__VA_ARGS__ << std::endl;} while(0)
#endif
...

APPLY(openlog, ((name.size() ? name.data() : nullptr), flags, facility);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The doubled opening parenthesis in your last line is erroneous.  Remove one.  The resulting code works for me in g++ in the way I think you intended.

Comment: For the future, it's useful to include any errors you're getting ("doesn't work" is not useful). See [ask].

Comment: In addition, in the second line, `(` just before `func(__VA_ARGS__);` might also be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using variadic templates instead of `VA_ARGS`, consider the following definition for the `ENABLE_FUNCS` case:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>                     
void apply(F&& f, Args&&... args) {                         
    std::initializer_list<int> l{                           
        (std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };                                                      
    (void) l;  // Silence compiler warnings                                             
}
```

`std::initializer_list` gives us a way to call `f` on each of our arguments in the given order. We're using a bit of a hack with the comma operator to let the expression evaluate to an `int` so that `l` is well defined for any return type `f` could have.

Finally, if `ENABLE_FUNCS` is not defined, you can provide this definition of `apply`:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>          
void apply(F&&, Args&&... args) {                
    std::initializer_list<int> l{                
        (cout << std::forward<Args>(args), 0)... 
    };                                           
    cout << endl;                                
    (void) l;                                    
}
```

We use the same strategy as before, with `initializer_list`, but in this case we are forwarding each argument to your logger.

Comment: The braced initializer hacks are not needed any more.  In C++17, you can just use a fold expression like `(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);`.  But it looks to me like the OP wants to just pass all arguments to one function call, not each argument individually in separate calls.